# iOS power button, can the event of touching it be determined?

Tags: ios

I'd like to know if there's a way to determine if the power button was hit to "close" the screen on the device.

Is there a way to determine this? I cannot use private api's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can tell if the button is pressed directly without using private APIs, however you might be able to use the `applicationWillResignActive:` method of the [`UIApplicationDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to do what you need to do.